# Installing python library "firedrake"

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing

I am using a MacBook Pro with Catalina, I have been following the directions given on the website:
https://www.firedrakeproject.org/download.html

to install firedrake, which is a finite element PDE solver. It installs with all the libraries. The problem is when I test the installation using their command "make alltest"
or try to import firedrake in a script I get the following error:

> ImportError: You cannot import h5py from inside the install directory.
>   Change to another directory first.

I am unsure what can I do to fix this issue. I would appreciate some help, thank you.

Things I have tried:
I updated both python, firedrake, and Homebrew. Tried copying and pasting the folder containing the h5py to another location, but that did not help. I believe there might be some issue with python and the way it is calling the h5py, library.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install that inside the directory you are in.

Come out of the directory and then try installing that, then it will work.

try using cd ~

Comment: So I have the install in my one directory. The install is done, I am trying to test ie call the the libraries such as h5py, I have tried in the same directory and others it does not matter, python cannot call it. I tried manually pasting the libraries from the firedrake directory to the python main folder and that did help with h5py, library but then then text package in fire drake had the same issue.

Comment: you do not need to move the libraries installed. Mention the path in the environment variables that will work.